# Batch file to read file names from CSV and rename files in a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

I have a set of codes in a file, i want to rename the files in a folder with that code. Like first code for the first file then second code for the second file.

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (code.csv) do call :rename "%%x" 
pause
GOTO :EOF

:rename
REN "*.jpg" "a/%1.jpg"
```

This is what I have written but this is like running the first code for all the files and am getting a duplicate file name that exists or the file can not found error. Even though the files are being renames but it takes lots of time which I believe due to some unnecessary looping.

Any help to make it perfect will be appritiated

Comment: How do you determine which file gets which name?

Comment: The specified target file name is not valid!

Comment: @Compo there is no order. First name goes to first file

Comment: Which is the first name? Which is the first file? How do you know that `code.csv` contains the same number of non empty lines as your current directory has files, _which can be renamed by the specific user_?

Comment: First file name from the CSV goes to the first file in the folder. Script can stop when either the name from CSV or files in the folder finishes first

Comment: How do you determine which is the first file in the folder?

Comment: There is no such order. There is no link between the file and the code. Any code from the csv can go to any file from the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to read the directory and the `csv` in parallel. There is a trick to do that:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
<code.csv (
  for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b *.jpg') do (
    set "NewName="
    set /p NewName=
    if not defined NewName goto :eof
    ECHO ren "%%x" "!NewName!"
  )
)
```

NOTE: remove the `ECHO` command after verifying it does what you want to actually enable the `ren` command.

`<code.csv ( ... )` provides one line after the other to the `set /p` within the `for` loop. Clear it before reading, so the `NewName` variable gets undefined, when there are no more names from the `csv`. Exit the `for` loop, when it is undefined (no more names).

The loop stops, when there are either no more files to be renamed or no more new names from the `csv` file.

See `dir /?` - especially the `/o` switch for how to sort the files (if needed) for names, dates or sizes.

Another possibility is to build an array of either the `csv` content or the files but I think that's an overkill for this task.